# Composer installed Amazon AWS SES PHP Classes not available

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, composer-php

I can't use the AWS SES PHP Classes although I already installed the AWS PHP 2 SDK via composer.

The PHP at root level is:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; //esto añade lo que gestiona composer
use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
$client = SesClient::factory(
                array(
                    'key' => $userid,
                    'secret' => $secret,
                    'region' => 'us-east-1' // SES has only us-east-1 endpoint, but can be used from global
                )
);
```

Browser execution is returning this:

**Fatal error: Class 'Aws\Common\Aws\Ses\SesClient' not found in /homepages/13/d357210024/htdocs/api/sendses.php on line 41**

The composer.json at root is just this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*"
    }
}
```

and the /vendor folders contain the aws, composer, guzzle and symfony packages along with the autoload.php that contains only this code:

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInita6b8287c70832f4f8a65e83c0ad07b6d::getLoader();
```

So... Could you point what I'm missing here?
Thank so much mates.

Comment: Maybe the classes are not available due this *vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php* emptiness...

        <?php

     // autoload_classmap.php @generated by Composer

    $vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
    $baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);
    
    return array(
    );

Comment: No, you should look at the `autoload_namespace.php` file and see that there is an entry for "Aws".

Comment: Your example works for me. Maybe check the permissions of the files aren't borked, and so they can't be loaded by PHP?

Comment: thanks Sven this my code:

    // autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer

   $vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
   $baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/event-dispatcher'),
    'Guzzle\\Tests' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzle/guzzle/tests'),
    'Guzzle' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzle/guzzle/src'),
    'Aws' => array($vendorDir . '/aws/aws-sdk-php/src'),
);

Comment: sorry but four spaces are not displaying the code format on the answers...

Comment: Thanks Danack, you mean to chmod -777 to all the vendor folder?

Comment: @arcovoltaico: You can edit your answer instead of commenting with unformatted code. But as far as I can see, it looks fine as expected.

Comment: I wonder why the class namespace that is not found is the concatenation of the two namespaces you are using. `use Aws\Common\Aws;` and `use Aws\Ses\SesClient;` leads to `Aws\Common\Aws\Ses\SesClient` not being found. Which version of PHP are you using? Maybe this is an already resolved bug, because I was not able to reproduce that behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for both inputs

Comment: PHP always has three numbers as the version. It is only slightly helpful to state the release, because IF we are talking about a bug, it would be necessary to know your and my exact version number, compare and then search the release notes or bug tracker for hints of a bugfix.

Comment: As a workaround, why don't you try this instead: `$client = \Aws\Ses\SesClient::factory()`

Comment: Nice tip. But it seems you were right about the permissions... really strange... I apply chmod 777 to vendors and now the class is available and my next challenge is fix the API specific error

Comment: btw this one (I'll check SES error ID doc): Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\Ses\Exception\MessageRejectedException: AWS Error Code: MessageRejected, Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID: eb2b082d-480c-11e3-8603-970df876f43f, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: Email address is not verified., User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.4.8 Guzzle/3.7.4 curl/7.21.0 PHP/5.4.21 thrown in /homepages/13/d357210024/htdocs/api/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php

Comment: @Sven I was using 5.4.21 sorry

Comment: Can I vote your answers?

Comment: Email address is not verified... tomorrow I'll fix it ;)

Comment: Now my e-mail is sent, I'm really glad :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is simpler than that. You have:

```
use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
```

With this, you've redefined the `Aws` namespace to mean something different the second time. If you're not actually using `Aws\Common\Aws`, then don't `use` it.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Ses\SesClient;

$client = SesClient::factory(array(
    'key'    => $userid,
    'secret' => $secret,
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
));
```

Comment: This is why your error message complains about `Aws\Common\Aws\Ses\SesClient`.

Comment: and what should we do if need this line Aws\Common\Aws ?

Comment: You can either set an alias for the class like this: `use Aws\Common\Aws as AwsClient` and reference it as AwsClient, but you should also be able to simply swap around the order of the use statements so that the Aws class is loaded last (Not too sure about that one though).